# Что мне нужно знать для запуска asp.net core application в wide web?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core

К примеру у меня есть простое asp.net core hello world приложение, я хочу уметь подключиться к нему через свой внешний ip и порт 80 из внешней сети (к примеру с телефона). Как? Какие технологии использовать, если я хочу это сделать из-под ubuntu?

Comment: а как запрос из внешней сети попадет на ваш веб сервер?

Comment: И что значит с телефона? С теефона из внешней сети или внутренней для вашего роутера, если у вас есть роутер?

Comment: [Размещение и развертывание ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/)

Comment: Я же могу сделать переадресацию ?

Comment: Вы предлагаете угадать что и куда вам надо переадресовывать?